# gitignore function shows no ignored files

Tags: c, git, gitignore

I'm a super beginner so I have no clue of anything almost - please bear with my silly questions, they are all related to the exercise you can see in the screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikJkD.png)

so

1. I have created a script ( git status --ignored --porcelain=v1 | grep '||' | sed 's/|| //' )
2. I run it in the terminal (ex05)
3. I see no output / no list of ignored files?

What am I doing wrong? what did I miss?

thxxxx

Answer (score 0):

You need first to create a .gitignore file, and specify all kind of files that you want them to be ignored. Otherwise, nothing will show up when executing git status.
For further information about .gitignore file, check this source: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gitignore-what-is-it-and-how-to-add-to-repo/